# Set authenticated user as value in Foreign key field before create an object using ModelSerializer with DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a simple endpoint to create an object using the ModelSerializer of Django rest framework. My model has a Foreign key to the User model, and I need set this value in the endpoint post functionality.

Working with forms in Django, you can add `commit=false` to the save method in the post, set the attribute `(instance.user = self.request.user)` and after that create the instance using the *save()* method. But, I can't find a clear and clean way to do it using Djago Rest Framework serlializaer.

This is my model.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    images_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=TICKET_STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=PENDING_TICKET,
    )

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
```

So, as you can see, there is a foreign key to the User model. In my post endpoint, this value must be filled with the authenticated user.

Take a look to the serializer:

```
class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('images_quantity',)
```

User only must to send images_quantity field value. So I need to create a new instance of the Ticket model, and set the authenticated user id as the value in the `created_by`field.

This is my view:

```
class TicketFormView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TicketSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            # Here is my problem. I need to set the created_by field before save.
            serializer.save()

            return Response(
                serializer.data,
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )

        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )
```

If I send the post, I get the `"null value in column "created_by_id" violates not-null constraint"`error, and this is because I need to set the authenticated user id in this field. How can I do it?

Comment: You can always initialize a form in your api view and use the serializer the same as you would form data. This essentially allows you to write regular Django view just substituting form data with the serializer. This may not be the most elegant option but is probably the easiest since you are familiar with it.

Answer (score 4):

Add created_by to list of serializer's fields and then you can just easily pass the authenticated user to serializer's save method:

```
serializer.save(created_by=request.user)
```

But I would suggest you to take advantage of rest framework's generics and do something like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics, serializers
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class TicketFormView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    permission_classes = ( IsAuthenticated, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

In this way, you don't have to implement any post method yourself as it is pretty standard way which you have done it.